# Appcelerator. Twitter auth in webview

Tags: twitter, appcelerator

I am trying to do a Twitter connection using a webview in the excellent Appcelerator Titanium. I know there is a great library from David R out, but I do not want to use a popup and I feel that I need more control over the flow.

My question is: During the authentication flow I need to get an oauth_token which (in my knowledge) is a combination of the consumer key and other values. How can I do this? How can I generate this token so that I can continue the process?

I am of course using Javascript.

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0):

It is a multi-step process based on the OAuth 1.0 specs, you can find the details at <http://oauth.net/core/1.0/>

Before doing anything, you will need to register an application with Twitter and they will provide you with a Twitter API Key and a Consumer Token (Key and Secret).

For the next steps, I highly recommend you use OAuthConsumer or some other library, but the steps include generating a proper request to get a "Request Token" from <https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token>
then using this Request Token, you need to request the user to authorize your application using <https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=REQUESTTOKENKEY>.

This last step provided you with a Request Verifier allowing your application to make the final request for a permanent Access Token from <https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token>.

When you receive the Access Token, you should store a copy somewhere so the user does not have to re-authenticate your application every time (unless that's what you desire).  This Access Token does not expire until the user specifically removes the access rights of your application from his Twitter profile.  Make sure to store the entire Access Token, meaning storing both the Key and the Secret.

Good luck!